# Intuition on Whitney–Graustein theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

According to the Whitney–Graustein theorem, two regular curves are regularly homotopic if and only if their winding numbers are the same.

Suppose I have a circular curve but with an extra loop so that the winding number is $2$. Intuitively, I would have thought that the loop can be contracted to a point continuously and hence the said curve and a circle is homotopic. But that is obviously not the case. Since the map we are concerned with is $H: [a, b] \times [0, 1] \to \mathbb R^2$ (where $[a, b] \in \mathbb R$ is the domain of the closed curve), the graph of $H$ is impossible to visualize. How can I intuitively see that the map $H$ which I described above (loop contracting to a point) is not a homotopy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a regular homotopy. There are points with tangent vectors in all directions which will limit to the point where the loop gets crushed. So this is not a smooth family of curves.

Comment: So it is a homotopy but not a regular homotopy. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.